# Zalgo characters on terminal with npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have an error on any terminal (git bash, cmd, powershell...). When running npm install or npm test command, I see "Zalgo" characters:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aX1Q.png)

Environment:

```
 SO Windows 10
 npm 8.1.2
 node v16.13.1
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I confirm that I have a similar issue: when I execute `npm test` in my angular app the screen gets filled with an infinite flow of random chars. However, the `build` and `start` commands work. The problem appeared this morning, after I executed a fresh `npm install` on the app.